# GeoServer Layer Group Default Style showing for every layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I'm using GeoServer to serve data by WMS.  They're all GeoTIFFs for now.  I've organized them into Layer Groups (Container Tree).

When I use the Data Source Manager in QGIS to connect to the server, it lists all the layer groups, which can expand to the layers, which can expand to "default-style" and "raster" (and "dem" in the case where I added that as an option).

I've searched and experimented and haven't found a way to prevent it from showing the "default-style" under every single layer.  When I add it as a layer in QGIS, it shows nothing.  I know it is somehow related to the layer group, as when I have these layers outside of the layer group, the "default-style" does not appear.

Anyone know how to get rid of that "default-style" entry from every layer in the group?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your GeoServer version is recent enough then you can turn the default styles off by going to WMS settings and uncheck this setting:

[image]